# jQuery ajax request being block because Cross-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, cross-domain

How to get content from remote url via ajax?

jQuery ajax request being block because Cross-Origin

**Console Log**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x28j5hv.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x28j5hv.
>   (Reason: CORS request failed).

**Code**

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x28j5hv",
type:'GET',
contentType: "html",
crossDomain:true,
success: function(data){
   //$('#content').html($(data).html());
   var src = $(data).html();
    alert(src);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @D4V1D Sorry, I forget to add it into my question. How to get content from remote url via Ajax?

Comment: Setting `crossDomain:true` doesnt set the cross domain request. the site must enable CORS in order for this to work.

Comment: @RoyiNamir can you please more explain? I'm new to jquery.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try to use `JSONP` in your Ajax call. It will bypass the Same Origin Policy.

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Try example

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x28j5hv?fields=title",

    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }

});
```

Comment: jsonp actually worked but the response data shows me an error. `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

{"result":[{"id":1,"cat_name":"travel","imgpath":"http:\/adas\/asd","` and points to the colon after "result" , what does this mean ?

Comment: That means that it failed to parse the response. When you use a jsonp the response should be something like CALLBACK({...JSON...}). you can define CALLBACK specifying "jsonpCallback" in your ajax parameters or it will be random generated and sent to the request as a field named "callback"

Comment: Same error as Abilash. But my API doesn't support `jsonp` and neither can I add or enable it. How can you fix cross origin with plain `json`?

Comment: @MrFaisal have you tried with an other video id? The video mentioned in answer is deleted

Comment: GET from jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 405

Comment: This is `Method Not Allowed` error. Make aure GET is allowed

Answer (score 18):

There is nothing you can do on your end (client side).  You can not enable crossDomain calls yourself, the source (dailymotion.com) needs to have CORS enabled for this to work.

The only thing you can really do is to create a server side proxy script which does this for you.  Are you using any server side scripts in your project?  PHP, Python, ASP.NET etc?  If so, you could create a server side "proxy" script which makes the HTTP call to dailymotion and returns the response.  Then you call that script from your Javascript code, since that server side script is on the same domain as your script code, CORS will not be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, but yes, you can do !!!! try use HttpClient, then you can get a string html. It's works for me. click in this link to confirm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597665/how-to-get-content-body-from-a-httpclient-call

Comment: @Marinpietri The HttpClient runs on the server.  We are talking about client side limitations here.  CORS is not an issue in server-to-server communication.

Comment: Ok! I just would like help him to solve the problem using an workaround. Thks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with cURL request for cross-domain.

If you are working through third party APIs or getting data through CROSS-DOMAIN, it is always recommended to use cURL script (server side) which is more secure.

I always prefer cURL script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the file path in the browser:

- Instead of: `c/XAMPP/htdocs/myfile.html`
- I wrote: `localhost/myfile.html`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
            url: "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x28j5hv?fields=title",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            format: "json",
            success:function(json){
                console.log('message: ' + "success"+ JSON.stringify(json));                     
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log('message Error' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }  
        });    
/* <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> */
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

If the source is a server you have access to, then you can open up cross-domain access for a specific folder (and it's sub-folders) with an `.htaccess` file located in appropriate folder:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```