# AJAX set host in header

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I able to do a request with fiddler.
When I try the same request with ajax it does not work because cross origin is not allowed.
Why cann't I set another host and origin in ajax?

Comment: This has been answered so many times it hurts :-)
For example, here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513450/jquery-ajax-request-being-block-because-cross-origin/31514305#31514305