# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call an api get request by the ajax method but I am getting the `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` error, I have set header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` but still I am getting this error also while setting the header why does the HTTP GET request changes to OPTION.
here is my code.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.ontraport.com/1/objects?objectID=5",
        type: 'GET',

        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
          'Api-Appid': '********',
          'Api-Key': '*******',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
              console.log(error);
        },
    });
```

Comment: That header needs to be set on server for response...not as request header. You can't force an api that is not CORS enabled to be enabled

Comment: The server responding should have the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`

In this case you have made the client sent that header.

Comment: For reference, http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31513450/1681154

Comment: @Elsie: you need to set your server to allow CORS (Access-control-allow-origin), in PHP via `header`(http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)

Comment: @DennyHiu My platform is ruby on rails

Comment: Do you control the endpoint you are calling in question? If not you will need to use your server (or third party service) as a proxy