# getting cross origin error while calling local Node service from html

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, nodes, node-modules

I have node service that runs on locahost and i am calling this service in HTML standalone page using ajax GET method.
But this gives me no access control allow origin error please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax request being block because Cross-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513450/jquery-ajax-request-being-block-because-cross-origin)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already partially been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

If you Did write the API yourself, please add the following header to your API:

**NodeJS:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

More detailed information can be find in the stack overflow question that has already been answered.