# how to i POST headers and body to a URL by javascript or jq?

Tags: javascript

This is my `JavaScript` function that does the `POST`

```
function loging() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://192.168.207.203:8443/e_ec_check",  
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: "json",  
        cache: false,   
        headers: {ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        body: {username: "admin", password: "admin"},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);  

            if (response.auth === 1) {
                window.location.href = "https://192.168.207.203:8443/#/app/dashboard";  
            } else {
                $("#invalid").show();   
                centered($("#invalid"));

                $(window).resize(function() {
                    centered($("#invalid"));
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#invalid").hide();
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
}

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="loging()" />
```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting, Or what do you expect and it is not happening?

Comment: I used the postman software to POST is OK, but javascript always show me error and i just only set a header and two body data in the postman. this is  my error pic  [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/lPrpCZU.jpg)

Comment: look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513450/jquery-ajax-request-being-block-because-cross-origin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068