# How to Remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while calling google API Distance Matrix by jQuery

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

How to Remove the this error

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
[image]

while calling google API Distance Matrix by jQuery

use this source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=[API_KEY]", function(data, status){
      console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Distance Matrix is available through the Google Maps Javascript API if you intend to use it client-side. You are calling the web service which is intended to be used server-side.

Answer (score 1):

This is cross origin issue. For security reasons browser blocks the requests made from different domain. You have to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in your http request to specify that your domain has the access to the api you are hitting.

You can refer this question [jQuery ajax request being block because Cross-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513450/jquery-ajax-request-being-block-because-cross-origin)

Alternatively you can disable the same origin policy for chrome for testing. For reference [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: I have added that to my code but it doesn't work. It occurs the same error setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: You can try after disabling same origin policy for chrome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome