# Read the DOM of an html page with an http call or the like

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, xmlhttprequest

I have an HTML page at the following address:
https://www2.casailaria.it/news/
I wish I could read some elements of the DOM with an http call via javascript. 
I'm trying them all, but I still have that damned console error: `CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" missing`.
I tried the following ajax call without success, studding it with alleged parameters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MAURIZIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax("https://www2.casailaria.it/news/", {
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cors: true,
            secure: true,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // or 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }); 
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope I'm not too far from the solution, and I think I'm going around it. Once obtained I would simply like to do operations like: `response.getElementsByClassName('myClassOfOtherPage')`
What do I have to add/remove to make it work well?
Other javascript solutions are welcome as well as ajax calls, as long as they are part of the CDN.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess your problem is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing

Comment: I tried, nothing. In that question, however, reference is made to a json and not to an html page. Another thing that is not specified is where to place the code `<IfModule mod_headers.c>Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"</IfModule>`. And both that and other questions almost never specify where to put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`. Only by doing a lot of browsing I discovered that it had to go inside `headers`...! Remains the fact that the problem is not solved.

Comment: I think you are getting confused. Access-Control-Allow-Origin comes in the Response Header and is not something you will send to a site. It is a security mechanism to prevent the access of resources from unknown domain. 
read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: So how do I read the dom? If you think about it I guess it's feasible and not against security. If anyone can view the page source, why can't I access the dom elements via javascript?

Comment: I am no master at these thing. The web site you are trying to reach is a news web site so they will have a very strong security. You cannot enable the cross-site access or read policy by yourself  at client side. What you can do is use a proxy if you are using some server side scripting language. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513450/jquery-ajax-request-being-block-because-cross-origin

Comment: Server side is easy, I've already done it with basic php. The problem is that he needs a web server to run... Client side would have been a great challenge.

Comment: @Memmo you can't proxy forbidden CORS requests clientside. You can use CORS proxies like [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/) to fetch the data.

Comment: I tried the native client side part but it doesn't work. It doesn't give me a mistake but I don't see anything...

Comment: if i am not clearly missing something, you need a crawler or a scrapper to achieve the required functionality , the endpoint is not an API that you can access . take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php) for a solution in PHP

Answer (score 1):

CORS is meant to protect the user from stealing sessions and data on other websites where the user is logged in.

The page that you are trying to load through AJaX is hosted on a different domain.

If you are developing locally, and just want to test, you can start Chrome with a flag to ignore CORS. [Here is how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

If you want to host your page on a different domain, you need to add the CORS header to `https://www2.casailaria.it/news/`. If that page is created using PHP, you can add this to that page:

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Note that * is not safe. It should be the domain of the page from which the AJaX call is originating.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the php, it would have been perfect otherwise, the page in question would have done it all like this...

Comment: If you can't change the source page, then it will never be possible to fetch it with AJAX from a different domain.

Comment: I could, but via client. The page is static and fully developed with html css and javascript + bootstrap...

Answer (score 1):

I just found this site is hosted by Apache. Normally you have to enable cors on Apache before you can call it from a different domain.

To enable cors on Apache, check this out https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

After you enable it on the backend site. Try it again and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might like to put the relevant part of the links in your answer as the links may be removed or get expired.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fixes you can try implementing :

1. Add CORS addon to your browser and enable it when you access your page.

or

2. Add "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" before your url that is mentioned in your ajax call. So resulting url will be 
   `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www2.casailaria.it/news/`

These things will work when you are accessing code locally.

If you opt for option 2 following will be the structure of your ajax call:

```
         $.ajax("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www2.casailaria.it/news/", {
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cors: true,
        secure: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // or 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I see a plausible solution. At this point, how should the ajax call be structured? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I am just suggesting to modify url and keep your ajax call structure same as you have. I have added the modified ajax call to my answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to request the page from the browser if they're Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers won't allow it.

You could set up a little server and request the page no problem on the back end, or you could use some kind of proxy that makes that request for you and returns the data. There used to be a proxy called anyorigin that would do that, but it's offline. Probably because that sort of thing is sketchy.