# .NET MVC, asynchronous task in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

i'm new in asynchronous programming in asp and i have a question and problem. i Would like to connect to external api and i created my class Task, here is a znippet of class

```
    public class Tasks
{
    HttpClient httpc = new HttpClient();

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> getStations()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll");
        var response = await httpc.GetAsync(uri);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> getStationDetails(int id)
    {
        string path = "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/sensors/" + id;
        var uri = new Uri(path);
        var response = await httpc.GetAsync(uri);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> getStationValues(int id)
    {
        string path = "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/data/getData/" + id;
        var uri = new Uri(path);
        var response = await httpc.GetAsync(uri);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Then i create asyncronous controller for my request, where i prepare data to response

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> prepareAirContitionData(int id)
    {
        Task<string> taskStationDetails = tasks.getStationDetails(id);
        string stationDetail = await taskStationDetails;

        List<Station> stationsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Station>>(stationDetail);

        List<Task<string>> stationsValues = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach(var station in stationsObj)
        {
            stationsValues.Add(tasks.getStationValues(station.stationId));
        }

        string[] war = await Task.WhenAll(stationsValues.ToArray());
        Console.Write(war);
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is the draft of my task. Problem is in te loop when i gather tasks and await for it, they doesn't show in my array of string, there is fill only one variable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are hitting the same issue as this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597665/how-to-get-content-body-from-a-httpclient-call)

You need to pass back the extracted response

Comment: But i would like to prepare data to reponse, i would like to process this data

Comment: Ok , i think i help me , i check this solution

Comment: This doesn't work i have the same value in all loop :/