# A large number of requests and deadlock in HttpClient (C#)

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, deadlock

I have a WPF application. One of its main tasks is to send POST requests and receive responses. Until recently, everything worked properly. However, the application is developing, I have implemented new functionalities and it turned out that I am probably sending too many requests.

I have only one instnce of the browser. My browser implementation inherits from `HttpClient` class and contains the following method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoPostRequest(string path, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data)
        {
            var urlRequest = this.BaseUrl + path;
            var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
            try
            {
                responseMessage = await base.PostAsync(urlRequest, requestContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (responseMessage == null)
                {
                    responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                }
                responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
            }

            return responseMessage;
        }
```

If I care about the answer (and in most cases it is), I use the following method:

```
        public async Task<string> DoPostRequestAndReadContent(string path,  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data)
        {
            var request = await this.DoPostRequest(path, data);
            return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

When I implementing my solution, I suggested the following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598059/6342204

---

**Usage**:
I use the above methods in the following way:

```
var response = this.DoPostRequestAndReadContent("/api/doSomething", data).Result;
```

---

**Problem**: 
I use the above class in various places of the project. It worked fine for me for a long time, but now there is a problem from time to time. The number of requests I send has recently increased. I am currently sending several to a dozen or so requests per second. The application sends them, the server receives them, but **I don't get a response**.

**Possible cause**:
I have read about this problem and many people indicate that the source of the problem may be a **deadlock**. Because I use `Result` when reading the response from the request, my code is no longer asynchronous. However, I don't know how else I could read the content that received from the api. The method `DoPostRequestAndReadContent` returns me a `Task<string>` object.

In this way, I think the usage of `.Result` is *inevitable*. Am I wrong? Maybe...

I would like to ask you for help in solving this problem. I was looking for similar topics, but none of them helped me. I only slightly changed the implementation of my methods (you could see them above), but this did not solve the problem. Requests are sent, but the responses aren't read.

Comment: do not block in async code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I think I should delete the ```.Result```. Am I right? But how can I read the content as a ```string```? My code must know the server response (possible errors, operation ID and so on).

Comment: Any blocking calls, like `Result` or `Wait()` can cause a deadlock in WPF app, try to call your method like `var response = await this.DoPostRequestAndReadContent("/api/doSomething", data);`

Comment: `DoPostRequestAndReadContent` returns a `Task<string>`, so you `await` for it. As you did in your methods. Maybe you just don't know where to put the `async` keyword? Btw, is your HttpClient static?

Comment: "I have a WPF application." That's great, WPF supports async/await so you don't have to use .Result or .Wait().  You just didn't post how WPF interfaces with the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide more context, it may help readers understand how you are consuming this function in your application, but the solution that makes sense, is to `await` it. `async/await` is viral. You end up propagating it up the entire call stack.

Just to be clear, `await` allows the existing thread to go off and do other things and then come back, when you `.Result`, it's like calling `await` but making it synchronous and blocking.

```cs
var response = await this.DoPostRequestAndReadContent("/api/doSomething", data);
```