# C# HttpClient Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, httpclient

I cant force to work HttpClient Post request...

or rather, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong..

My code below and this's sketch

```
        #region Method 2
        HttpClient h = new HttpClient();
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            //{ "csrf_token" , "aacc347b22df2a7b3a20c9674ba59cf4279c8d16:1552967983844" },
            //{ "track_id", "501c86f19b745703e9ca54991e90dc3a87" },
            //{ "password", "Oguhokuu13" }
        };
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); // Content-Type
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("UTF-8"));
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://passport.yandex.ru");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36");
        // h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth/welcome?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Ftaxi-cabinet.mobile.yandex.ru%2Fnews%2F");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "passport.yandex.ru");
        h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");



        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = h.PostAsync("https://passport.yandex.ru/auth/add", content);
        response.Wait();
        var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        textBox1.Text = responseString.ToString();
        #endregion
```

Then I get response:

```
\u001f?\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003sN???/Q\b?\u000f\u000eQ?O,-??OLI?\u0002\0d(,h\u0016\0\0\0"
```

Idk what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Perhaps the response is GZip compressed (since you indicate in your request that you support that). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990601/decompressing-gzip-stream-from-httpclient-response).

Comment: Also see [this article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) on `HttpClient`.