# Is there any strong reason why to not always use DecompressionMethods.All?

Tags: c#, .net-core, compression

I had an a de-compression issue with after mismatching between the `Accept-Encoding` value and the `AutomaticDecompression` value of the `HttpClientHandler`,

In this case, I was missing the `| DecompressionMethods.Brotli` on `AutomaticDecompression` after having an `Accept-Encoding` of `, br`:

```
services.AddHttpClient(E_HttpClient.Typicode.ToString(), client =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, br");
    //...
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
});
```

So I could resolve this issue by Option 1:

```
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Brotli
```

Or by option 2:

```
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
```

Is there any strong reason why not always keep the `DecompressionMethods` to `All` **always** as a best practice?

Comment: `DecompressionMethods.All` also includes `Deflate`.

Comment: Hey @DavidL, yes I can tell that based on my experiment, but in regard to my question I would like to know if I can always use it, why to bother with defining the others?

Comment: It’s really opinion-based. Do you want to be all inclusive of new compression standards in your code simply by upgrading the underlying libraries or do you want to opt in? How you choose to proceed is going to vary for each organization and use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless you're concerned about the (usually negligible) increase in CPU for decompressing.

There is also no guesswork happening on the client, you send the compression methods you support with Accept-Encoding, and the server selects the most suitable one and includes it in the response header Content-Encoding.

If low latency is prioritized, using compression is usually faster than not. At least if you trust the server to have a suitable compression based on a normal message size.

Note that HttpClient has no compression enabled as default, so it's good practice to [set it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327208/2440).