# httpClient.GetStringAsync is giving me encrypted HTML content

Tags: c#, html, string, web, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get the HTML source code from a web page with this code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "search app");

var sourceCode = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

I tried with many web pages, and I didn't have any problem. Everything works fine, and the result is the HTML content of the web page as a string.

But now I'm trying with Amazon (in the URL use for example "https://www.amazon.com") and the result came encrypted. I can't even copy the result to show you.

What is happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: I very much doubt that it's *encrypted*. I think it's much more likely that it's compressed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990601 for an option for automatic decompression.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) who [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76964371/httpclient-getstringasync-is-giving-me-an-encripted-html/76964643#comment135677546_76964371):

> I very much doubt that it's encrypted. I think it's much more likely that it's compressed. See [Decompressing GZip Stream from HTTPClient Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990601/decompressing-gzip-stream-from-httpclient-response) for an option for automatic decompression.