# Reading more than one JSON file into a memory stream

Tags: c#, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have some c# code that happly reads the contents of a .gz file (which contains 1 .json file) into a memory stream and finds the first instance of "[" and obtains data after that. However, depending on the amount of data I have sent that creates the gz response, it may contain more than 1 .json file.
How can I change my code so it either removes the header and any following JSON files "starters", or (prob a better option) reads each file in turn into a memory stream and obtains the data needed?

Current code snippet is

```
string responseBodyUrl = getResponseObject.response_body_url;

// get the tar.gr file and expand
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(responseBodyUrl);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
gzipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
gzipStream.Close();
stream.Close();
memoryStream.Position = 0;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
string memstreamjson = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
memoryStream.Close();

// find the index of the first '[' character
int index = memstreamjson.IndexOf('[');
                                  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"memstreamjson.log",memstreamjson.ToString().TrimEnd() + Environment.NewLine);

// if found
if (index != -1)
 {
  // get the substring from that index to the end
  string indexedmemstreamjson = memstreamjson.Substring(index);

  // parse the JSON string as an array
  JArray arr = JArray.Parse(indexedmemstreamjson.ToString());
  
  // loop through each element of the array
  foreach (JObject obj in arr)
   {
    // get the status_code value of the JObject
    string status_code = (string)obj["status_code"];
etc
```

gz file input (multiple (2) files) looks like :

`./                                                                                                  0000755 0000000 0000000 00000000000 14512730710 007711  5                                                                                                    ustar   root                            root                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ./0q6hnae8uz.json                                                                                   0000666 0000000 0000000 00016772531 14512730710 012547  0                                                                                                    ustar   root                            root                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [{"status_code":200,"operation_id":null,"response":"{\"id\":\"19159244156b70211d3e26b64ce38fc2\",\"email_address\":\"bobbobbington@bobmail.com\"}]                                                                                                                                                                       ./46kbba2abt.json                                                                                   0000666 0000000 0000000 00000007550 14512730710 012441  0                                                                                                    ustar   root                            root                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [{"status_code":200,"operation_id":null,"response":"{\"id\":\"0ec0b4c07a27c60069735d321875fa78\",\"email_address\":\"sammy:sammymail.com\"}]`

Many Thanks in advance

Tried the above code which finds when there is only one JSON file in the gz, but fails when there are multiples.
I'm expecting to get the beginning of each JSON file and then read the read-line content to the console.

Comment: Try to fix the indentation of your code its unreadable currently. Same goes for your file example. Shorten it to something that is readable and sufficiently to show the problem. Sufficiently means showing how the multiple Json are formed. Presumably the inner complex Json structure isn't part of the problem but makes it unreadable.

Comment: Done. apologies.

Comment: This look like [TAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) format to me. Is that correct?

Comment: When you are on Net.7 the framework has a [TarReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.tar.tarreader?view=net-7.0) you can hand your MemoryStream over that will help you navigating and extracting the single "files" from the TAR archive.

Comment: it is, depending on the amount of data sent, 1 or more .json files, in a TAR file, in a gz.

Comment: Mind that `WebClient` is not recommended for new code. For the recommended alternative `HttpClient` this may be of interest to you, then: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20990601/982149