# How to fill the DataGridview Datasource with the List?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a List of string type in which I am storing some values and then inserting them into the database. Now I want to show those values into the Gridview when I fill my GridView data source with that List it only shows the total number of characters of each value in the list. Is there any procedure that I show the list values into the DataGridView.

My code below is as follows:

```
private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<string> SerialNumberList = new List<string>();

        int SerialNumberStart = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(StartSerialBox.Text, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty));
        int SerialLimit = Convert.ToInt32(LimitBox.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < SerialLimit;i++ )
        {
            SerialNumberStart++;
            SerialNumberList.Add("S" + SerialNumberStart);


        }

         for (int j = 0; j < SerialNumberList.Count;j++ )
         {
            Adapter.insertserialnumbers(SerialNumberList[j] , DateTime.Now.ToString()); //Insertiona Procedure which will save the values into the database.
         }
        SerialGridView.DataSource = SerialNumberList ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `BindingList`
for example :

```
protected void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<ListType> SerialNumberList = new BindingList<ListType>();
        int x = 5;
        SerialNumberList.Add(new ListType(x.ToString()));

        grid.DataSource = SerialNumberList;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
public class ListType
{
    public ListType()
    { }
    private string Itemname;

    public ListType(string _ListItem)
    {
        ListItem = _ListItem;
    }
    public string ListItem
    {
        get { return Itemname; }
        set { Itemname = value; }
    }


}
```

Comment: But I do not have to pass the "Hello" I have to pass the Textbox value and so its giving me null exception.

         SerialNumberList.Add(new SerializationReportRecord("S"+SerialNumberStart.ToString()));

As in first I have to concatenate it with the "S" and then pass that value. Please tell me some other way I can do this

Comment: It gives me exception that Entity classes need default constructors!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [extention method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) for `IEnumerable`(here `List`) type object from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523153/how-do-i-transform-a-listt-into-a-dataset). Use this extention method to create `DataTable` from `SerialNumberList` and bind to DGV like this:

```
SerialGridView.DataSource = SerialNumberList.ToDataTable();
```